# Outputting variable to text file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to output some variables to a logging text file. Here's what I'm doing now...

```
' Copying $DevRoot\$File to $RemoteRoot\$ServerName\$File' >> $LogFile
```

But it's outputting that exactly....

```
Copying $DevRoot\$File to $RemoteRoot\$ServerName\$File
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes. Double quotes tell PowerShell to interpret any variables or escaped characters before rendering, while single quotes are interpreted literally.